# How to do these pattern borders on Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector

[image: 2000s Belarusian Army patch]

I've been pondering how to make the specific border style like in this patch in Inkscape since I'm already quite confused at this point.

How to do the patch border on Inkscape like in this image? I'm still new on this regards.

[image: Close up]

(also forgive me for bad English I wrote this in 12 AM. Disclaimer it's non political and for reenactment and digitalization of Belarusian historical symbols project. I don't support the war as well. Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the Pattern Along a Path LPE in Inkscape, and a little manual work to finish it off.

Here's a brief overview:

Draw a single rope-like element, and copy it to the clipboard. I drew this on top of the graphic you shared, to try to get it the same size. Then copy this shape to the clipboard.

[image]

Then you can add the Pattern Along Path LPE, using the Link to Path in Clipboard button. You can see the settings I used below in the Path Effects panel. I have also used an Offest Path effect to bring the path inside the shield shape.

[image]

This effect tends to mess up at the corners, so you could convert the path effect to actual editable objects using *Path > Object to path*. Delete and replace the messy corners with shapes that fit.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! i really appreciate this! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Valentin - you can show thanks by ticking it as the right answer.